# How to change the displayed image/gif based on interaction state in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I have an app which needs to display the image and gif based on the interaction state respectively

Here is my code

```
#import "InteractionView.h"
#import "FLAnimatedImage.h"

@interface InteractionView() {
CADisplayLink *_displayLink;
UIImage* micImage;
FLAnimatedImage *image;
FLAnimatedImageView *imageView;
}
@end

@implementation InteractionView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    [self initialize];
}

return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
[super awakeFromNib];
[self initialize];
}

- (void)initialize {
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
micImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"mic_button.png"];

_displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(redrawView:)];
[_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

_interactionState = image;
NSURL *imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"button_audio" withExtension:@"gif"];
NSString*stringPath = [imgPath absoluteString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringPath]];
image = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:data];
imageView = [[FLAnimatedImageView alloc] init];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[_displayLink invalidate];
[_displayLink removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
_displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)setInteractionState:(InteractionState)interactionState {
if (_interactionState == image && interactionState != image) {
    _displayLink.paused = NO;
}

_interactionState = interactionState;
}

- (void)redrawView:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink {
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
if ( _interactionState == gif) {
    imageView.animatedImage = image;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 40, CGRectGetMinY(frame), 70, 70);
    [self addSubview:imageView];   
} else if (_interactionState == image) {
    UIBezierPath* micPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 40, CGRectGetMinY(frame), 70, 70)];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [micPath addClip];
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
    CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 40, CGRectGetMinY(frame), 70, 70), micImage.CGImage);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}
@end
```

When i launch the app the interaction state is image so the image is getting displayed when the interaction is changed to gif the gif is displayed after that if the interaction is again changed to image but the image is not getting displayed instead the gif is played continuously

How to solve it the issue so that if the interaction state is image then image should be there and if the interaction state is gif then gif should be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drawRect and reDrawView is changed as

```
- (void)redrawView:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink {
if ( _interactionState == gif ) {
    imageView.animatedImage = image;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(40, 0, 70, 70);
    imageView.tag = 17;
    [self addSubview:imageView];   
}
if( _interactionState == image ) {
    UIView *viewToRemove = [self viewWithTag:17];
    [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
}
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIBezierPath* micPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(40, 0, 70, 70)];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
[micPath addClip];
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, CGRectMake(40, 0, 70, 70), micImage.CGImage);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```